# Implement the Apriori algorithm in R language without using the apriori() function

Tags: r

I am trying to implement the Apriori using R language but the important part is not using the function `Apriori()` I should build it from scratch. so I did the code but there is a problem on my code and I couldn't solve it. what I did in the code is this:  I Implement `Fk−1 × F1` methods.
but my problem is when i tried to input binary it throw an error with missing value!! i replaced the missing value to 0 but still it throw an error! i think the problem in converting original market basket in to binary form!!

and here is my code:

```
    multi_col = function(data_frame) {
  multivec = data.frame(val = rep(1,nrow(data_frame)))
  for(q in 1:ncol(data_frame)){
    multivec = multivec*data_frame[q]
  }
  return(multivec)
}

item = c("onion","potato","milk","burger","beer")
t1 = c(1,1,0,1,0)
t2 = c(0,1,1,1,0)
t3 = c(1,1,1,0,0)
t4 = c(1,1,1,0,0)
t5 = c(1,1,1,1,0)
t6 =c(1,1,1,1,1)

data_mat= rbind(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6)
data_mat
colnames(data_mat)=item
data_mat # this is the example data frame i used to develop the code

data_mat = as.data.frame(data_mat)
data_mat

min.sup.thresh = 2
max.item = ncol(data_mat)
max.item

for(k in 1:max.item){

  if(ncol(data_mat)>1){

    Candi = list()
    Freq =  list()

    rm_col = numeric(0)

    C_seq = combn(c(1:ncol(data_mat)),k)

    for(i in 1:ncol(C_seq)){

      Candi[[i]] = colnames(data_mat[C_seq[,i]])

      if(sum(multi_col(data_mat[C_seq[,i]]))>=min.sup.thresh){
        Freq[[i]] = colnames(data_mat[C_seq[,i]])
      }else{
        rm_col = c(rm_col,i)
      }

    }
    data_mat=data_mat[(-rm_col)]
    print(paste("number of generated candidate itemsets","in C",k,"is",length(Candi)))
    print(Candi)
    print("****************************")
    print(paste("total number of frequent itemsets","in F",k,"is",length(Freq)))
    print(Freq)
    print("###################################################################################")


  }


}
```

could you please give me any suggestion on how to do it!?

Comment: I tried an anwser but can you provide the error you get to expand your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using your code and what appear is that with `k==5` the line `combn(c(1:ncol(data_mat)),k)` get an error because there is only 4 columns to data_mat. I don't really get all your code but I think its because you modify data_mat during your loop. I set a new variable called `tmp_data_mat`, so that error don't occur.

Another option could be modification of `data_mat` outside of the `for-loop`

Also, note there is a missing value in milk, and it work by addition of the `na.rm = TRUE` in the `sum` function you use.

```
# I create data_mat on another way
data_mat <( data.frame(onion = c(1,0,rep(1,4)), 
                       potato = rep(1,6), 
                       milk = c(NA,rep(1,5)), 
                       burger = c(1,1,0,0,1,1), 
                       beer = c(rep(0,5),1)))
data_mat

min.sup.thresh = 2
max.item = ncol(data_mat)
max.item

for(k in 1:max.item){

  if(ncol(data_mat)>1){

    Candi = list()
    Freq =  list()

    # modification here about rm_col, so it don't eat all your memory.
    rm_col = seq(ncol(data_mat))

    # here is the issue I think
    C_seq = combn(c(1:ncol(data_mat)),k)

    for(i in 1:ncol(C_seq)){

      # don't think you need a function multi_col so I put it inside
      data_frame <- data_mat[C_seq[,i]]

      Candi[[i]] = colnames(data_frame)

      multivec = data.frame(val = rep(1,nrow(data_frame)))
      for(q in 1:ncol(data_frame)){
        multivec = multivec*data_frame[q]
      }

      # the missing value error was because you missed the na.rm = TRUE in the sum function !
      if(sum(multivec, na.rm = TRUE) >= min.sup.thresh){
        Freq[[i]] = colnames(data_mat[C_seq[,i]])
      }else{

        # follow the modification of rm_col
        rm_col = rm_col[-i]
      }

    }

    # here is the BIG modification of your code it don't show error.
    tmp_data_mat=data_mat[rm_col]
    print(paste("number of generated candidate itemsets","in C",k,"is",length(Candi)))
    print(Candi)
    print("****************************")
    print(paste("total number of frequent itemsets","in F",k,"is",length(Freq)))
    print(Freq)
    print("###################################################################################")

  }

}
```